# How to Resolve Forces and Balance their Components?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, energy-conservation, vectors, rigid-body-dynamics

In Newtonian Mechanics, the resolution, balancing and conversion of given forces into their components is perhaps the most important part and I seem to be unversed in it. For the most part, I fluidly know **the types of forces, Newton's Laws and Conservation of energy and the resolution of vectors**.

What I can't understand is that which forces are **helping in the motion** and which of them are **opposing it**.

Can anyone please tell me clear steps on  how to balance the forces and resolve their vector components?

Comment: The force with the greater magnitude will dominate and the particle will accelerate at the exact same direction as that of the force which is dominating (force with the greater magnitude).

Comment: @TejasDahake What you wrote about the force with "greater magnitude" is totally misleading.

Comment: @Marko Gulin Obviously if two forces acting in the opposite direction to each other then the direction of the net force will be as same as the direction of that one force among the two forces which is greater in magnitude. What's wrong with this statement? Explain me thoroughly...??

Comment: @Marko Gulin I think you thought that the force will not reduce that means you interpreted it wrongly, it's not like that I think the OP is still qualified enough to understand this that the force which is dominating will get reduced at the amount equal to the magnitude of force with smaller magnitude.

Comment: I mean let's say force $F_1$ has greater magnitude and force $F_2$ has smaller magnitude as compared to $F_1$ and both of them are acting in the opposite direction and will get subtracted. And the direction of $F_1$ will dominate which will be equal to the magnitude $|F_1 - F_2|$ which will be our net force . And this is already understood.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "helping" and "opposing" motion? Do you mean causing an object to accelerate or decelerate, respectively?

Comment: Well,acceleration and retardation is one way to look at it.In this question however,in the above question the effect of component of forces on motion and applying it on questions is discussed.Please refer to the answer and post comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you mention

> I fluidly know the types of forces, Newton's Laws and Conservation of energy and the resolution of vectors

> Can anyone please tell me clear steps on how to balance the forces and resolve their vector components?

Since you say you are fluid in resolution of vectors, it is not clear to me what do you mean by *"how to resolve their vector components"*

I am going to give here brief instructions how to do free-body diagram, although I am sure all of this is already explained in your textbook.

---

**COORDINATE SYSTEM**

This is the first step you need to do. Decide how many axes do you need and set their positive direction. An axis arrow usually shows in the positive direction. In vector analysis these axes are usually labeled as $\hat{\imath}$, $\hat{\jmath}$, and $\hat{k}$, where the hat indicates unit vector.

**FREE-BODY DIAGRAM**

Setup the free-body diagram of the point mass, i.e. draw all the forces that act on the mass with respect to the coordinate system you've setup in the previous step. The two things students are usually doing wrong in this step are: (i) they include *reaction forces* (third Newton's law) to the diagram - this is wrong, you must include only the **forces that act on the object**; (ii) they include $m a$ force in the diagram - this is wrong, because it is a consequence of the net force, **not the force itself**.

**WRITE FORCES IN THE COORDINATE SYSTEM**

Find the orthogonal projection of each force to all axes in the coordinate system. In case of a 2D coordinate system this is

$$\vec{F} = (F \cos\theta) \hat{\imath} + (F \sin\theta) \hat{\jmath}$$

where $F$ is the force magnitude and $\theta$ is the angle between the force vector $\vec{F}$ and positive $\hat{\imath}$ axis in the **clockwise direction** starting from the force vector. It must be noted that the $F \sin\theta$ term is valid only if the $\hat{\jmath}$ axis is 90$^\circ$ anti-clockwise with respect to the $\hat{\imath}$ axis.

**FIND THE RESULTANT FORCE**

Once you write all forces in the respective coordinate system, add them together. This is called vector sum. The second Newton's law says:

$$m \vec{a} = \vec{F}_\text{net}$$

where $\vec{F}_\text{net}$ is the resultant force, and $\vec{a}$ is the acceleration vector which points in the same direction as the resultant force.

---

To answer your question

> What I can't understand is that which forces are helping in the motion and which of them are opposing it.

you first must decide what defines “the motion”: velocity (displacement) vector or acceleration vector. If you ask me I would say the former, but I am not sure if it is strictly defined. Then just compare directions of the “motion vector” and the force vector. You can do this graphically or by using the vector scalar product:

$$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = |\vec{a}||\vec{b}| \cos\theta = a_i b_i + a_j b_j$$

where $|\vec{a}|$ denotes length (magnitude) of a vector and by definition is always positive. When the $\cos\theta$ term is positive then the force vector in question supports (helps) the motion, and when it is negative it opposes the motion, hence

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
a_i b_i + a_j b_j > 0 & \text{vectors point in the same direction} \\
a_i b_i + a_j b_j < 0 & \text{vectors point in the opposite direction} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

If you decide the motion direction to be defined by the *displacement vector*, then forces that support motion do positive work and forces that oppose motion do negative work. The forces that are perpendicular to the motion direction do no work!

Comment: Well,i understand how to draw the  free body diagram and the basic principles per se .What I don't understand is which forces are playing role in the motion and which are opposing them and how to express them in equations clearly

Comment: @ParagEkbote Please see if adendum to my post answers your question.

Comment: @ParagEkbote please take a look at the comments above I think I've answered it what you want correctly while talking to Marko Gulin if still it's not what you want then please edit the question and try to elaborate the question In depth.

Comment: The things you have added certainly has given me additional clarity and that was the perspective I was looking for.Also,can you tell me that what sinθ of a force does for the motion and while drawing the FBD,any additional care needs to be taken?

Comment: @ParagEkbote The $\sin\theta$ is used only to find vector projection to $\hat{\jmath}$ axis, but only if $\hat{\jmath}$ is defined to be 90$^\circ$ anti-clockwise to $\hat{\imath}$! It also makes no difference to the FBD in graphical sense. If you find that my post answers your question(s), please consider accepting it so that your question does not appear as unanswered. Note that you do not have to accept any answer if you feel it does not provide information you were asking for.

Comment: Yes,I have just done it, your initial explanation was known to me but the latter part was really helpful and I am grateful for that.Soon, I am going to write specific rules and cases to deal with different types of numerical's based on the above theory and needed a better understanding of the topic,which you have given exceptionally.